# Calculation on keyup for multiple rows(Row Created by button click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using below code to generate the textbox on a button click. Now i want to multiple the value of text1 with text2 and fill it in text3 on keyup event, and repeat the process for each row. I don't know how to use keyup and multiple the data of each row. plz help. 
JS CODE:

```
$(function(){
insertRow();
$('#addrow').on('click',function(){
insertRow();
});
function insertRow() {
var index = $('#noofrows').val();
var table = document.getElementById("rep1");
var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

var day1=row.insertCell(0);
    var t1=document.createElement("input");
            t1.id = "text1"+index;
            t1.name = "text1[]";
    var day2=row.insertCell(1);
        var t2=document.createElement("input");
            t2.id = "text2"+index;
            t2.name = "text2[]";
            var day3=row.insertCell(2);
        var t3=document.createElement("input");
            t3.id = "text3"+index;
            t3.name = "text3[]";
           index++;
$('#noofrows').val(index);

}
});
```

HTML BUTTON CODE:

```
<div id="myDiv1">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive table-striped" id="rep1">
<input type='button' name='addrow' id='addrow' value='Add Row' class="btn btn-primary">
<tr>
<tr>
    <th rowspan="2" >Text1</th>
    <th rowspan="2" >Text2</th>
    <th rowspan="2" >Text3</th>
</tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot put input or any other html element without `tr` and `td`/`th` inside table. So keep add and index input outside the table. As you are already using jquery then don't use javascript to create elements as it will take more code and time (jQuery is little simpler to use). 
Attache keyup event with inputs from first and second column and put its multiplication under third column
Try below code.

```js
$(function(){
insertRow();
$('#addrow').on('click',function(){
insertRow();
});
function insertRow() {
var index = $('#noofrows').val();
var table = $("#rep1 tbody");
table.append('<tr><td><input type="text" id="text1' + index + '" name="text1"></td><td><input type="text" id="text2' + index + '" name="text2"></td><td><input type="text" id="text3' + index + '" name="text3"></td></tr>');
index++;
$('#noofrows').val(index);
}

$("#rep1").on("keyup"," input[name^=text]", function(){
   var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
   var val1 = $tr.find('td:eq(0) input').val();
           var val2 = $tr.find('td:eq(1) input').val();
           $tr.find('td:eq(2) input').val(val1*val2);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv1">
<input type='button' name='addrow' id='addrow' value='Add Row' class="btn btn-primary">
<input id="noofrows" value="0">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive table-striped" id="rep1">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th rowspan="2" >Text1</th>
    <th rowspan="2" >Text2</th>
    <th rowspan="2" >Text3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

in above code, we are already getting different id where i have used `index` and attaching it with each input id, same you can follow to create different name.
Change keyup event handle with [start with attribute selector in jquery](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and read first, second and third input using `eq()` selectors as shown below

```
$("#rep1").on("keyup"," input[name^=text]", function(){
       var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
       var val1 = $tr.find('td:eq(0) input').val();
       var val2 = $tr.find('td:eq(1) input').val();
       $tr.find('td:eq(2) input').val(val1*val2);
    });
```

Comment: can you plz suggest how do i get different name like different id & run the code

Comment: i think it's giving same name for every textbox like text1 text2 text3 and same for new row

Comment: you need to give some static unique name for each text box as i did for id. Example `id="text1' + index`, `id="text2' + index` and `id="text3' + index` so final id for row 1 will be text11, text21 and text 31 and for row2 will be text12, text22, text32 .. follow same and give name as `name="text1' + index` etc

Comment: ya id is different but i want to access this name in other code. It will create a problem for that code.